# Random Number Picking

Tags: probability, random

Take $4$ random numbers in the range of 0-255.

What is the chance that three of them fall into the lower 32 (0-31) and one falls into the higher 32 (224-255),
OR one falls into the lower 32 and three fall into the higher 32?

The answer is $\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^{3}$ (I've written a script that runs 1000 loops)

The question is: Why?

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the chance that three of them fall into the lower 32 (0-31) and one falls into the higher 32 (224-255), OR one falls into the lower 32 and three fall into the higher 32?

Disjoint events have additive probabilities.

The count for disjoint success events among a sequence of independent and identically distributed trials is a *Multinomially Distributed Random Variable*.

Thus the probability is $\bbox[lemonchiffon]{\tbinom 43 {(\tfrac{32}{256})}^3\tfrac{32}{256}+\tbinom 41 \tfrac{32}{256}{(\tfrac{32}{256})}^3}$, which simplifies to your answer.

That is all.

Answer (score 0):

The possibility of one number falling into lower 32 is $\frac{32}{256}=\frac{1}{8}$. Same as for higher 32.

If we pick four numbers and the possibility of one falling into lower 32 and the rest falling into higher 32 is $4\cdot\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^{4}$.
The possibility of one falling into higher 32 and the rest into lower 32,  is also the same.

Therefore you get the answers $4\cdot\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^{4} + 4\cdot\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^{4} = \left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^{3}$.

Comment: Thank you.The thing is the equation you wrote does not add up for me:

    `(1/8)^4 + (1/8)^4 = 4,8828125e-4`
and
    `(1/8)^3 = 0,001953125`

Comment: @SzépeViktor You are right! My answer was totally wrong! Sorry to make you confuse. I have corrected my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the correction.